# Function Within Struct that Has Input Type of that Struct

Tags: c, struct

Tongue twister title, but I'm really probably just overthinking it.

I have a struct that has a callback function pointer in it that takes as input parameter a type that is that struct. How to go about it?

```
typedef struct my_type my_type;

void (*my_callback_f)(my_type *Type);

struct my_type
{
   my_callback_f my_callback;
};
```

The compiler obviously does not like this but hopefully it illustrates what I'm after. Like I said, I'm probably just overthinking context pointers.

**Edit (Instantiating):**

```
my_type *TheThing = { MyFunction };
```

where

```
void MyFunction (my_type *Type)
{
 //stuff
}
```

This results in the function address in the object's function pointer not matching the known address for MyFunction.

Comment: You forgot a `typedef`.

Comment: C or C++?  Don't count on the answer being the same.

Comment: It's C.  Yes C++ would certainly be easier.

Comment: In your "Edit" comment -- could you show what the function pointer is and what you expected it to be?   `my_type *TheThing` should probably just be `my_type TheThing` -- ie, remove the `*`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have the function pointer type in the original question. `void (*my_callback_f)(my_type *Type);` Sorry that might have been vague. I keep ending up with the TheThing having an address a value like 0xf11136, with the function pointer struct member having address 0xB65E9, but the function itself is at 0xf11ca0. If I manually inject the 0xf11ca0 into the debugger the function gets called like I would expect... so it really seems like I'm just not referencing the function correctly when I want to call it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worst case, just forward declare the struct;

```
struct my_type; // this is the forward declaration
typedef void (*my_callback_f)(struct my_type *Type);

struct my_type
{
   my_callback_f my_callback;
};
```

Comment: This compiles, but the problem I end up with is that iniatializing the struct does not create a pointer match. Will edit my instantiation into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to "answer" my own question simply because I solved my issue, but I'll accept Soren's as the answer since his answer technically answers the subject question I asked originally.

The function pointers were throwing illegal access errors because I had not malloc'ed the struct that I had instantiated. Once I did that it called the function just fine, despite having different values according to the debugger.